# LINQ: "contains" and a Lambda query

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, lambda

I have a `List<BuildingStatus>` called `buildingStatus`. I'd like to check whether it contains a status whose char code (returned by `GetCharCode()`) equals some variable, `v.Status`.

Is there some way of doing this, along the lines of the (non-compiling) code below?

```
buildingStatus.Contains(item => item.GetCharValue() == v.Status)
```

Answer (score 367, accepted):

Use [**`Any()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any) instead of `Contains()`:

```
buildingStatus.Any(item => item.GetCharValue() == v.Status)
```

Answer (score 39):

The Linq extension method **Any** could work for you...

```
buildingStatus.Any(item => item.GetCharValue() == v.Status)
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is how you can use `Contains` to achieve what you want:

`buildingStatus.Select(item => item.GetCharValue()).Contains(v.Status)` this will return a Boolean value.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure precisely what you're looking for, but this program:

```
    public class Building
    {
        public enum StatusType
        {
            open,
            closed,
            weird,
        };

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public StatusType Status { get; set; }
    }

    public static List <Building> buildingList = new List<Building> ()
    {
        new Building () { Name = "one", Status = Building.StatusType.open },
        new Building () { Name = "two", Status = Building.StatusType.closed },
        new Building () { Name = "three", Status = Building.StatusType.weird },

        new Building () { Name = "four", Status = Building.StatusType.open },
        new Building () { Name = "five", Status = Building.StatusType.closed },
        new Building () { Name = "six", Status = Building.StatusType.weird },
    };

    static void Main (string [] args)
    {
        var statusList = new List<Building.StatusType> () { Building.StatusType.open, Building.StatusType.closed };

        var q = from building in buildingList
                where statusList.Contains (building.Status)
                select building;

        foreach ( var b in q )
            Console.WriteLine ("{0}: {1}", b.Name, b.Status);
    }
```

produces the expected output:

```
one: open
two: closed
four: open
five: closed
```

---

This program compares a string representation of the enum and produces the same output:

```
    public class Building
    {
        public enum StatusType
        {
            open,
            closed,
            weird,
        };

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }

    public static List <Building> buildingList = new List<Building> ()
    {
        new Building () { Name = "one", Status = "open" },
        new Building () { Name = "two", Status = "closed" },
        new Building () { Name = "three", Status = "weird" },

        new Building () { Name = "four", Status = "open" },
        new Building () { Name = "five", Status = "closed" },
        new Building () { Name = "six", Status = "weird" },
    };

    static void Main (string [] args)
    {
        var statusList = new List<Building.StatusType> () { Building.StatusType.open, Building.StatusType.closed };
        var statusStringList = statusList.ConvertAll <string> (st => st.ToString ());

        var q = from building in buildingList
                where statusStringList.Contains (building.Status)
                select building;

        foreach ( var b in q )
            Console.WriteLine ("{0}: {1}", b.Name, b.Status);

        Console.ReadKey ();
    }
```

---

I created this extension method to convert one IEnumerable  to another, but I'm not sure how efficient it is; it may just create a list behind the scenes.

```
public static IEnumerable <TResult> ConvertEach (IEnumerable <TSource> sources, Func <TSource,TResult> convert)
{
    foreach ( TSource source in sources )
        yield return convert (source);
}
```

Then you can change the where clause to:

```
where statusList.ConvertEach <string> (status => status.GetCharValue()).
    Contains (v.Status)
```

and skip creating the `List<string>` with `ConvertAll ()` at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks larry that worked, here is what i did by refering to your code... But it would be nice if possible if i didn't have to create a new list????

// Used ToList because its an ILIST and run my GetCharValue
// this produces a "NEW" list with my char's
var statusStringList = building.ToList().ConvertAll<char>(st => st.GetCharValue());

            var test = from v in qry
                       where statusStringList.Contains(v.Status)
                   select v;

All works, as i say it would be nice not having to do a new list or using a lambda inside Contains but appears its NOT possible?

Comment: I assume the status property is a string; you therefore have to convert the status enums to strings for each comparison. You might as well convert them once at the beginning and be done with it.

Comment: I've made an edit that significantly simplifies the question but, in doing so, sort-of-invalidates this answer. Sorry about that, but I figured it was for the greater good overall.

Answer (score 0):

```
var depthead = (from s in db.M_Users
                  join m in db.M_User_Types on s.F_User_Type equals m.UserType_Id
                  where m.UserType_Name.ToUpper().Trim().Contains("DEPARTMENT HEAD")
                  select new {s.FullName,s.F_User_Type,s.userId,s.UserCode } 
               ).OrderBy(d => d.userId).ToList();

Model.AvailableDeptHead.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "0" });
for (int i = 0; i < depthead.Count; i++)
    Model.AvailableDeptHead.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = depthead[i].UserCode + " - " + depthead[i].FullName, Value = Convert.ToString(depthead[i].userId) });
```

Comment: here I'm try to match my userType form user type table to user table for t collect department head name  hope sa

Answer (score -2):

If I understand correctly, you need to convert the type (char value) that you store 
in Building list to the type (enum) that you store in buildingStatus list.

(For each status in the Building list//character value//,
does the status exists in the buildingStatus list//enum value//)

```
public static IQueryable<Building> WithStatus(this IQueryable<Building> qry,  
IList<BuildingStatuses> buildingStatus) 
{ 
    return from v in qry
           where ContainsStatus(v.Status)
           select v;
} 


private bool ContainsStatus(v.Status)
{
    foreach(Enum value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(buildingStatus)))
    {
        If v.Status == value.GetCharValue();
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: -1; while my edit to the question has slightly invalidated this answer by removing all reference to `Building` from the question, this was already *really broken*. `foreach(Enum value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(buildingStatus)))` is nonsense.