# LINQ with non-lambda for Any Contains

Tags: linq

How do you do Linq with non-lambda express for the following (which does not work):

```
string[] words = { "believe", "relief", "receipt", "field" }; 
var wd = (from word in words
          select word).Any(Contains ("believe"));
```

Comment: This question which is very similar appears to have been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566439/linq-help-with-contains-and-a-lambda-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what good you believe the `from wor in words select wor` is doing - it's really not helping you at all.

It's also not clear why you *don't* want to use a lambda expression. The obvious approach is:

```
bool hasBelieve = words.Any(x => x.Contains("believe"));
```

Note that this isn't checking whether the list of words has the word "believe" in - it's checking whether the list of words has any word *containing* "believe". So "believer" would be fine. If you *just* want to check whether the list contains `believe` you can just use:

```
bool hasBelieve = words.Contains("believe");
```

EDIT: If you *really* want to do it without a lambda expression, you'll need to basically fake the work that the lambda expression (or anonymous method) does for you:

```
public class ContainsPredicate
{
    private readonly string target;

    public ContainsPredicate(string target)
    {
        this.target = target;
    }

    public bool Apply(string input)
    {
        return input.Contains(target);
    }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
Func<string, bool> predicate = new ContainsPredicate("believe");
bool hasBelieve = words.Any(predicate);
```

Obviously you really don't want to do that though...

EDIT: Of course you *could* use:

```
var allBelieve = from word in words
                 where word.Contains("believe")
                 select word;

bool hasBelieve = allBelieve.Any();
```

But that's pretty ugly too - I'd definitely use the lambda expression.

Comment: Thank Jon, how can you do it with non-lamda as I like to see how it is done.

Comment: @NatePet: See my edit, but it's not really clear whether that's what you mean. What exactly did you have in mind by "non-lambda"?

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like that

```
string[] words = { "believe", "relief", "receipt", "field" };
var wd = (from wor in words
          where wor.Contains("believe")
          select wor);
```