# Lambda/Linq with Contains criteria for multiple keywords

Tags: c#, linq

I have to lists

1. Main list with Comments field
2. List of keywords to search for.

I want to search the keywords in each Comment field of each record which in SQL would look like below

```
select * from MainList
where Comment like '%keyword1%'
or Comment like '%keyword2%'
... so on until the last keyword.
```

So far I have seen examples but usually for single keyword at a time only
e.g. [LINQ with non-lambda for Any Contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511875/linq-with-non-lambda-for-any-contains)

What I would like is to search each record in MainList for any instance of any of my keyowrds all at once.
something like:

```
var newList = MainList.Where(m => m.Comments.Contains(purposes))
```

I would prefer doing it in lambda syntax but if not possible, linq is also okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering for my and others' reference.

```
var newList = MainList.Where(m => keywords.Any(k => m.Comments.Contains(k))).ToList();
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with EF Core 5

Answer (score 15):

Added extension method which can help in generating such predicate. Usage is simple:

```cs
var newList = MainList
   .FilterByItems(keywords, (m, k) => m.Comments.Contains(k), true)
   .ToList();
```

And implementation:

```cs
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> FilterByItems<T, TItem>(this IQueryable<T> query, IEnumerable<TItem> items,
        Expression<Func<T, TItem, bool>> filterPattern, bool isOr)
    {
        Expression predicate = null;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var itemExpr = Expression.Constant(item);
            var itemCondition = ExpressionReplacer.Replace(filterPattern.Body, filterPattern.Parameters[1], itemExpr);
            if (predicate == null)
                predicate = itemCondition;
            else
            {
                predicate = Expression.MakeBinary(isOr ? ExpressionType.OrElse : ExpressionType.AndAlso, predicate,
                    itemCondition);
            }
        }

        predicate ??= Expression.Constant(false);
        var filterLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(predicate, filterPattern.Parameters[0]);

        return query.Where(filterLambda);
    }

    class ExpressionReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        readonly IDictionary<Expression, Expression> _replaceMap;

        public ExpressionReplacer(IDictionary<Expression, Expression> replaceMap)
        {
            _replaceMap = replaceMap ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(replaceMap));
        }

        public override Expression Visit(Expression exp)
        {
            if (exp != null && _replaceMap.TryGetValue(exp, out var replacement))
                return replacement;
            return base.Visit(exp);
        }

        public static Expression Replace(Expression expr, Expression toReplace, Expression toExpr)
        {
            return new ExpressionReplacer(new Dictionary<Expression, Expression> { { toReplace, toExpr } }).Visit(expr);
        }

        public static Expression Replace(Expression expr, IDictionary<Expression, Expression> replaceMap)
        {
            return new ExpressionReplacer(replaceMap).Visit(expr);
        }

        public static Expression GetBody(LambdaExpression lambda, params Expression[] toReplace)
        {
            if (lambda.Parameters.Count != toReplace.Length)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();

            return new ExpressionReplacer(Enumerable.Range(0, lambda.Parameters.Count)
                .ToDictionary(i => (Expression) lambda.Parameters[i], i => toReplace[i])).Visit(lambda.Body);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this work?

Comment: @Chris It takes the `filterPattern` and basically builds up an expression that applies that to each value in the `items` and then or's them together.  So this example would create an expression equivalent to `m => m.Comments.Contains(keyword1) || m.Comments.Contains(keyword2) || m.Comments.Contains(keyword3)` where `keywords` contains `keyword1`, `keyword2`, and `keyword3`.

Comment: I think this is a little complicated because it tries to solve two issues at once. `Contains` for one value works just fine. Isn't the main issue having a dynamic number disjunctions? The `LinqKit` package has a `PredicateBuilder` for that.

Comment: @OliverSchimmer, are you sure that you want to loop over all items and apply predicate builder? This answer helps to avoid that and avoids additional third party dependency.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv You too are iterating over all items in your expression builder. I cannot see how you can build an expression tree without doing so.

Comment: @OliverSchimmer, I have created extension to do not iterate every time by myself. It is much effective than LINQKit, in which I contribute also.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv That wasn't the debate. It does not matter who iterates, the code you provided will still be in your project, and a maintenance nightmare for anyone who stumbles over it.

Comment: @OliverSchimmer, for which purpose it has to be maintained? It works or not. And it works for years for others. Complex part is 12 lines of simple Expression Tree remapping code.

Comment: Hey, great result, being quite familiar with building Expressions I still didn't really understand the `ExpressionReplacer` with it's `Visit` method. Somehow it also magically ignores cases. Could you perhaps add some docs per method to better understand it? Don't want it to look like ChatGPT generated this piece of code :D