# EF Core how to rewrite the query in a form that can be translated

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I`ve got a query and in one part i need to add this:

```
List<string> list = *some list of strings*
query = query.Where(a => list.Any(x => EF.Function.ILike(a.Name, $"{x}%")));
```

It worked before, but after update my ef library i got this error:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet
> ...' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

How can I change my query for workable state again? I noticed that without `.Any()` it works.

```
query = query.Where(a => EF.Function.ILike(a.Name, "string1%") || EF.Function.ILike(a.Name, "string2%"));
```

But I cant do it manually. Is there a proper way to fix it?

Comment: What do you need Any() for ?  Especially if it is working without this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67666649/lambda-linq-with-contains-criteria-for-multiple-keywords/67666993#67666993) my answer for extension method `FilterByItems`. Then you can do the following:

```cs
List<string> list = *some list of strings*
var patterns = list.Select(x => x + "%");

var result = query
    .FilterByItems(patterns, (a, p) => EF.Function.ILike(a.Name, p), true);
```