# how use like in sql on linq c#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

this not work

```
string[] DATE_Group = { "2020", "2021" }; //changing values
var query = _context.c10
            .Where(u => DATE_Group.Any(s => u.ON_DATE.Contains(s)))
            .ToList()
            .Select(u => new
            {
                User_NumberID = u.User_NumberID.ToString(),
            }).ToList();
```

I use this `u.ON_DATE.Contains("2020")` and work but not list or array only one value

in sql `SELECT *  from C10 where ON_DATE like '%2020%' or ON_DATE like '%2021%'`
and in ON_DATE column content like this 1-3-2023 1-1-2021 5-1-2020

this error when used
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcIIk.png)

Comment: and in ON_DATE column content like this 1-3-2023 1-1-2021 5-1-2020

Comment: Are you getting any error? if so please share it. If the output is unlike the expected, share it as well. @sp 4_4

Comment: The `ON_DATE` column is `DATE`/`DATETIME` type?

Comment: Answered similar a lot of times. There is no support in EF Core for such query, but with helper function you can do that: [answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69823896/10646316), [answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68164647/10646316). If it is still not clear, will create another similar answer,

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv FilterByItems not work my API

Comment: Well, probably we need another similar answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF Core cannot use `Any` with local collections (with small excpetion), only `Contains` is supported.

I would suggest to use function [FilterByItems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67666649/lambda-linq-with-contains-criteria-for-multiple-keywords/67666993#67666993). And use in query:

```cs
string[] DATE_Group = { "2020", "2021" }; //changing values

var query = _context.c10
    .FilterByItems(DATE_Group, (u, s) => u.ON_DATE.Contains(s), true)
    .Select(u => new
    {
        User_NumberID = u.User_NumberID.ToString()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this below code for your linq where statement.

```
var myVar=context.Students.where(x=>x.Name.Contains("John")).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: the same this u.ON_DATE.Contains("2020") I want multiple values

Comment: Multiple like this ("2020","2021","2022") ?

Comment: yes in sql  SELECT *  from C10 where ON_DATE like '%2020%' or ON_DATE like '%2021%' or ON_DATE like '%2022%'

Comment: var myVar=context.Students.where(x=>x.Name.Contains("John")||x.Name.Contains("Joseph")).SingleOrDefault();

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a better way to get the data:

```
var from = new DateTime(2020,1,1);
var to   = new DateTime(2022,1,1);
var query = _context.c10
            .Where(u => u.ON_DATE > from && u.ON_DATE < to )
            ...
```

Comment: This is the real answer