# Using local sequence in LINQ to SQL with EF Core

Tags: linq, .net-core, linq-to-sql, ef-core-3.1

I am using .NET 3.1 with Entity Framework Core 3.1.
In my query, I want to look for projects where at least one of my provided search strings are contained in a project's name

```
var projectSearchStrings = new List<string>() { "Test", "Fake" };

var projects = from p in Projects
                where projectSearchStrings.Any(x => p.Name.Contains(x))
                select p;
```

when i execute this query with .ToList() i get the following Exception

```
The local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.
```

I already performed similar queries in an older Project using .NET Framework with EntityFramework (not Core).

Is there a way to perform such queries with a local sequence in EF Core?

Comment: EF Core supports only `Contains` with in-memory collections. Try to use [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67666993/10646316) it will generate needed ExpressionTree.

Comment: interesting approach, works perfectly in my case, thank you!