# How I can add Or instead of And in custom QueryableExtension Npgsql text[]? If its possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql, dbextensions

I need help with **queryableExtension** for **Npgsql** string array.

I have column in database as type **Text[]**. This contains multiple values and I want to search in them but not with AND but with OR.

I have query extension which work fine, search in whole string array, but with all are equals.

```
public static IQueryable<T> ContainsOfStringArray<T>(this IQueryable<T> source,
    PropertyInfo property, string[] values)
{
     source = source.Where(_ => values.All(v => EF.Property<string[]>(_, property.Name).Contains(v)));

     return source;
}
```

I have data

```
record 1 - string[] { AAA, BBB }
record 2 - string[] { AAA }
```

If I pass one parameter **AAA** then return 2 records. If **BBB** return 1 record.

BUT if I pass two parameters **AAA,BBB** then return 0 records.

**My question is "How I can add Or instead of And? If its possible".**

I tried wrote custom **Expression.Call** but without success. I don't know how call Contains function from Npgsql for right translate because string[] does not contain Contains function :(

If you have any idea how to write Expression.Call for predicate this would be excellent.

Using Asp.Net Core 3.1

Ty so much for help

**--- EDIT CLOSED----**

Change *All()* to *Any()* do right work.
Thanks to @IvanStoev comment

Comment: Not sure I understand the goal, but in general, `All` means *And*, `Any` means *Or*, so may be just use `values.Any` instead of `values.All`?

Comment: You can use [this ny extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67666993/10646316) to achieve expected result.

Comment: @IvanStoev aaahhh I am shame. You are absolutly right. With Any this work excellent. Many thanks