# FilterByItems Method not working correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

Im building a filter and im using the [FilterByItems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67666993/10646316) method to compare two Arrays(one from my frontend and one from my database). It all goes through a Overlay Panel in my Frontend, where the user can select different persontypes like member, worker and much more. So my problem is now that i got multiple persontype hovers which dont want do work together. If i just have one it works fine, if i add a second one it only works if both have the same values in the frontend list.

The right case would be:
Frontend Panel one got the Member in the Array, Frontend Panel two got the Friend in the Array.
Table shows all persons who are saved with these types in their profile.

The current and wrong case is:
Panel 1 and Panel two are not working with different arrays and only showing informations if both have the same list for example both got member on position [0]

Generelly it seems like it works as a single one as an and query and as the second panel joins in it blocks completely. So here is my code(FilterByItems Method is linked above):

```cs
//The Filter
//Login
[HttpPost("filter/")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Filter([FromBody] Filter user)
{
    var baseQuery = _context.Personens.AsQueryable();
    //Personentyp 1 Dont works in combination with below
    if (user.personenTypFilter.Length > 0)
        baseQuery = baseQuery.FilterByItems(user.personenTypFilter, (m, k) => m.Personentypzuordnungens.Any(i => i.Personentyp.Bezeichnung.Contains(k)), true);
    ////Personentyp 2
    //if (user.personenTypFilter2.Length > 0)
    //    baseQuery = baseQuery.FilterByItems(user.personenTypFilter2, (m, k) => m.Personentypzuordnungens.Any(i => i.Personentyp.Bezeichnung.Contains(k)), true);
    //---------------------------------
    var result = await (baseQuery.Select(p => new
    {
        personId = p.PersonId,
        nachname = p.Nachname,
        vorname = p.Vorname,
        plz = p.Plz,
        firmBez = p.Firmenbezeichnung,
        ort = p.Ort,
        personentyp = p.Personentypzuordnungens.Select(i => new
        {
            personentypId = i.PersonentypId,
        }),
        aktuellePosition = p.AktuellePosition,
        taetigkeit = p.Tätigkeit,
        kernkompetenzen = p.Kernkompetenzen,
        datenReviewedZeitpunkt = p.DatenReviewedZeitpunkt,
    }).ToListAsync());
    return Ok(result);
}
```

Thats how i declared my variables in my Filter Model:

```cs
public string[] personenTypFilter { get; set; }
public string[] personenTypFilter2 { get; set; }
```

New problem with .CombineAnd(from comments)

```html
baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(
                //Characteristics
                character1Predicate.CombineOr(character1Predicate2).CombineOr(character1Predicate3)
                //Persontypes
                .CombineAnd(personType1Predicate.CombineOr(personType2Predicate).CombineOr(personType3Predicate)));
```

Comment: So you need schematically `baseQuery.FilterByItems(user.personenTypFilter, ..,) || baseQuery.FilterByItems(user.personenTypFilter2, ..,)` ?

Comment: yes i think so. I already tried it like this too but i get a error: " || cannot be applied to operands of type IQueryable<Personen> and IQueryable<Personen>"

Comment: Sure you cannot. I need to improve `FilterByItems` - it's my function.

Comment: Ohh haha wow, that would be very nice!

Comment: Do you use LINQKit?

Comment: Currently not, never heard about it. But i can if  necessary

Comment: Not really, it has `PredicateBuilder` which may help here, but I can do that without this dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is evolution of [FilterByItems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67666649/lambda-linq-with-contains-criteria-for-multiple-keywords/67666993#67666993) and adds additional public methods for generating predicate and combining them.

You can use new extensions in your query in the following way:

```cs
var baseQuery = _context.Personens.AsQueryable();

var predicate1 = baseQuery.GetItemsPredicate(ser.personenTypFilter, (m, k) => m.Personentypzuordnungens.Any(i => i.Personentyp.Bezeichnung.Contains(k)));
var predicate2 = baseQuery.GetItemsPredicate(user.personenTypFilter2, (m, k) => m.Personentypzuordnungens.Any(i => i.Personentyp.Bezeichnung.Contains(k)));

// filter by combined predicates
baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(predicate1.CombineOr(predicate2));
```

And implementation:

```cs
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> FilterByItems<T, TItem>(this IQueryable<T> query, IEnumerable<TItem> items,
        Expression<Func<T, TItem, bool>> filterPattern, bool isOr = true, bool emptyValue = true)
    {
        var filterLambda = query.GetItemsPredicate(items, filterPattern, isOr, emptyValue);

        return query.Where(filterLambda);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetItemsPredicate<T, TItem>(this IEnumerable<T> query, IEnumerable<TItem> items, Expression<Func<T, TItem, bool>> filterPattern, bool isOr = true, bool emptyValue = false)
    {
        Expression predicate = null;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var itemExpr = Expression.Constant(item);
            var itemCondition = ExpressionReplacer.Replace(filterPattern.Body, filterPattern.Parameters[1], itemExpr);
            if (predicate == null)
                predicate = itemCondition;
            else
            {
                predicate = Expression.MakeBinary(isOr ? ExpressionType.OrElse : ExpressionType.AndAlso, predicate,
                    itemCondition);
            }
        }

        predicate ??= Expression.Constant(emptyValue);
        var filterLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(predicate, filterPattern.Parameters[0]);
        return filterLambda;
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> CombineOr<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate1,
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate2)
    {
        var parameter = predicate1.Parameters[0];
        var body = Expression.OrElse(predicate1.Body, ExpressionReplacer.GetBody(predicate2, parameter));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> CombineAnd<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate1,
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate2)
    {
        var parameter = predicate1.Parameters[0];
        var body = Expression.AndAlso(predicate1.Body, ExpressionReplacer.GetBody(predicate2, parameter));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, parameter);
    }

    class ExpressionReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        readonly IDictionary<Expression, Expression> _replaceMap;

        public ExpressionReplacer(IDictionary<Expression, Expression> replaceMap)
        {
            _replaceMap = replaceMap ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(replaceMap));
        }

        public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
        {
            if (node != null && _replaceMap.TryGetValue(node, out var replacement))
                return replacement;
            return base.Visit(node);
        }

        public static Expression Replace(Expression expr, Expression toReplace, Expression toExpr)
        {
            return new ExpressionReplacer(new Dictionary<Expression, Expression> { { toReplace, toExpr } }).Visit(expr);
        }

        public static Expression Replace(Expression expr, IDictionary<Expression, Expression> replaceMap)
        {
            return new ExpressionReplacer(replaceMap).Visit(expr);
        }

        public static Expression GetBody(LambdaExpression lambda, params Expression[] toReplace)
        {
            if (lambda.Parameters.Count != toReplace.Length)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();

            return new ExpressionReplacer(Enumerable.Range(0, lambda.Parameters.Count)
                .ToDictionary(i => (Expression)lambda.Parameters[i], i => toReplace[i])).Visit(lambda.Body);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great, ty! Good work

Comment: I have another question to this. So all is working fine, but i have another panel with characteristics for example "friendly" and much more. So im trying to combine these with combineOr and then combineAnd because its a filter. So it just should show all persons who are happy and a member, so my problem is now that it shows all peoples who are happy and all peoples who are members, it does not combine these. Got it like that (look in my post). But it only returns me 0 results, how is it possibile to handle this?

Comment: Not sure about your business logic. Use [ReadableExpressionsVisualizers](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1232914.ReadableExpressionsVisualizers) to examine what you have generated.

Comment: Downloaded the tool and did some google search because of the upcoming error:

When the BinaryFormatter is not supported on the debuggee-side, objects passed to the UI via the stream are formatted with JSON, call GetDeserializableObject instead.

Seems like the BinaryFormatter isnt anymore supported?

Comment: Looks like problem with selected target framework. Try this one aslo: [zspitz/ExpressionTreeVisualizer](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeVisualizer)

Comment: Okay, found the probleme. Didnt set isOr to false :D

Comment: So the Problem is still there. If im trying to filter with this:

baseQuery = baseQuery.Where(personType1Predicate.CombineOr(character1Predicate)); It does not shows me all clients who got skill 1 and 2. Instead of that he shows me all users who got 1 and all users who got 2

Comment: Write correct predicate with two items without any dynamic and FilterByItems and check what is returned. Sorry I so not have time debugging and understanding your database.

Comment: Okay i will try, np thx