# Find in Entity Framework multiple OR parameters

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Suppose I have a product in my database with the description “white shirt size 50”.

The search parameter would be “shirt 50”. I have a more complex query in which I add several “OR”s and I can't get them to work.

I get the following error:

> The LINQ expression
>
> 'DbSet()
> .Where(p => p.IdTienda == __request_IdTienda_0)
> .Join(
> inner: DbSet(),
> outerKeySelector: p => p.IdArticulo,
> innerKeySelector: a => a.Id,
> resultSelector: (p, a) => new TransparentIdentifier<Publicacion, Articulo>(
> Outer = p,
> Inner = a
> ))
> .Where(ti => __arrayrequest_1
> .Any(s => ti.Outer.Descripcion.Contains(s)) || ti.Outer.Codigo == __request_Filtro_SearchText_2 || ti.Inner.Codigo == __request_Filtro_SearchText_2 || ti.Inner.CodigoUniversal == __request_Filtro_SearchText_2 || ti.Inner.CodigoUniversalBulto == __request_Filtro_SearchText_2)'
>
> could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

My code so far is the following:

```
var arrayrequest = request.Filtro.SearchText.Split().ToList();

var query = from publicacion in _dbContext.Publicaciones.Where(p => p.IdTienda == request.IdTienda)
            join articulo in _dbContext.Articulos 
                 on publicacion.IdArticulo equals articulo.Id
            where
                arrayrequest.Any(s => publicacion.Descripcion.Contains(s))
                                 || publicacion.Codigo == request.Filtro.SearchText
                                 || articulo.Codigo == request.Filtro.SearchText
                                 || articulo.CodigoUniversal == request.Filtro.SearchText
                                 || articulo.CodigoUniversalBulto == request.Filtro.SearchText
            select publicacion;

var publicaciones = await query
                          .Include(p => p.Articulo)
                          .Include(p => p.TributoPublicacion)
                          .ToArrayAsync();
```

The error occurs in the section

```
arrayrequest.Any(s => publicacion.Descripcion.Contains(s))`
```

I use Entity Framework Core 5 - any help is welcome

Comment: In what way does it not work? Are you seeing an error? In which case you need to tell us what that error is. Or does it not return the results you expect? In which case you need to describe what you expect and what you are seeing, including the generated sql.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering, the first part is the exception that entity framework throws

Comment: I think EF Core only supports `.Any()` for exact matches. I think you'd need to perform multiple `EF.Functions.Like(...)` tests and or the results together. eg https://mitchelsellers.com/blog/article/using-predicatebuilder-with-ef-core-for-complex-queries

Comment: Thanks for answering it did indeed work with EF.Functions.Like, add a line var likeSearch = string.Format("%{0}%", string.Join("%", request.Filter.SearchText.Split())); and change the line that was causing conflict
arrayrequest.Any(s => post.Description.Contains(s))
by the following EF.Functions.Like(post.Description, likeSearch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't want to repeat myself, but it is good to show how it can be solved.

EF do not supports complex predicates with local collections and here you need to build expression tree dynamically. This answer has [GetItemsPredicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70017345/10646316) function which helps in building needed condition.

Then you can rewrite your query in this way:

```cs
var arrayrequest = request.Filtro.SearchText.Split().ToList();

var query = from publicacion in _dbContext.Publicaciones.Where(p => p.IdTienda == request.IdTienda)
            join articulo in _dbContext.Articulos 
                 on publicacion.IdArticulo equals articulo.Id
            select publicacion;
            
var descriptionPredicate = query.GetItemsPredicate(arrayrequest, (publicacion, s) => publicacion.Descripcion.Contains(s));

Expression<Func<Publicacion, bool>> otherPredicate = publicacion => publicacion.Codigo == request.Filtro.SearchText
                                 || articulo.Codigo == request.Filtro.SearchText
                                 || articulo.CodigoUniversal == request.Filtro.SearchText
                                 || articulo.CodigoUniversalBulto == request.Filtro.SearchText;

query = query.Where(descriptionPredicate.CombineOr(otherPredicate)));

var publicaciones = await query
    .Include(p => p.Articulo)
    .Include(p => p.TributoPublicacion)
    .ToArrayAsync();
```

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time and answering it's a good answer, but I just solved it by changing a line of my code... change the line “arrayrequest.Any(s => publication.Description.Contains(s))” to the following “EF.Functions.Like(post.Description, string.Format("%{0}%", string.Join("%", request.Filter.SearchText.Split())))".. that works for me

Comment: I ended up using your extension. It is very good and allows me to make more complex and efficient queries. thanks for sharing