# Using the LIKE operator in Dynamic LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, dynamic-linq, ef-core-6.0

**Note:** If you have the same problem and found this question before the "duplicated" one, be aware that the answer to that question does not work. I marked the only working solution below.

I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://dynamic-linq.net/advanced-entityframework#like-operator) which states that this should be possible in Dynamic LINQ:

```
var config = new ParsingConfig { ResolveTypesBySimpleName = true };
var example2 = Cars.Where(config, "DynamicFunctions.Like(Brand, \"%t%\")");
example2.Dump();
```

I'm using string concatination to build a complex query:

```
IQueryable<DtcViewEntity> queryable = ...
string[] values = { "%a%" };
string myOperator = "and"; // or sometimes "or"
bool isNot = false; // or sometimes "true"

var query = string.Join($" {myOperator} ", values.Select((value, index) => $"DynamicFunctions.Like(MyColumn, @{index})"));
if (isNot)  query = $"not ({query})";
var config = new ParsingConfig { ResolveTypesBySimpleName = true };
return queryable.Where(config, query, values);
```

But the actual error can be reproduced with code that looks almost identical to the example in the guide:

```
IQueryable<DtcViewEntity> queryable = ...

var config = new ParsingConfig { ResolveTypesBySimpleName = true };
var result = queryable.Where(config,  "DynamicFunctions.Like(MyColumn, \"%a%\")").ToList();
```

And I get:

```
System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Exceptions.ParseException : Enum type 'DynamicFunctions' not found
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseAsEnum(String id)
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseMemberAccess(Type type, Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseIdentifier()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParsePrimaryStart()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParsePrimary()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseUnary()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseMultiplicative()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseAdditive()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseShiftOperator()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseComparisonOperator()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseLogicalAndOrOperator()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseIn()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseAndOperator()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseOrOperator()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseLambdaOperator()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseNullCoalescingOperator()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseConditionalOperator()
```

I've seen [this code](https://github.com/zzzprojects/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/blob/6fc7fcc43b248940560a0728c4d181e191f9eec1/src-console/ConsoleAppEF2.1.1/Program.cs#L117) as well, but using `var config = ParsingConfig.DefaultEFCore21;` will result in

```
System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Exceptions.ParseException : Enum type 'DynamicFunctions' not found
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseAsEnum(String id)
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseMemberAccess(Type type, Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParseIdentifier()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParsePrimaryStart()
   at System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Parser.ExpressionParser.ParsePrimary()
```

After adding `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DynamicLinq` to the dependencies I get:

```
System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Exceptions.ParseException : No applicable method 'Like' exists in type 'DynamicFunctions'
```

[Falco Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5273580/falco-alexander) even found a "[working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rFGM80)" form ZZZ Projects that produces the very same error message:

```
Unhandled exception. Enum type 'DynamicFunctions' not found (at index 21)
Command terminated by signal 6
```

I can't find any information on this exception, so my question is: what am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you import Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DynamicLinq?

Comment: @FalcoAlexander Thanks, that did at least _something_. Now I'm getting `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Exceptions.ParseException : No applicable method 'Like' exists in type 'DynamicFunctions'`

Comment: Which EF version do you use? Please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: @GertArnold I'm using EF Core 6.0 and Dynamic LINQ 1.2, i.e. it's just the newest Nuget packages I could get.

Comment: EF Core 6 or EF 6? Two different libraries.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv EF Core 6.0.

Comment: I can write this condition without Dynamic.LInq. It will be faster and reliable.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Can I? I have a list of values "%t%" which I need to concatenate via AND or OR. Right now I'm doing this via string concatenation (or I would if "Like" worked).

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rFGM80 is providing a working example but I run exactly into the same errors you get when executing the code in my VS2022 or Linqpad

Comment: @StefanS. Update question with information what you are trying to build. Looks like I have answered similar several times.

Comment: @StefanS. updated his question focussing on the error more than looking for a solution. The single code line in my answer does it quite well...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Get Extension methods from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70017345/10646316). It contains `GetItemsPredicate` function, which will help in building predicate.

Then we can generate needed predicate without `Dynamic.Linq` and avoid raw text parsing.

```cs
// input parameters
string[] values = { "%a%" };
var isOr = true;
var isNot = false;

var predicate = queryable.GetItemsPredicate(values, (e, v) => EF.Functions.Like(e.MyColumn, v), isOr);

if (isNot)
{
    // inversion
    predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<DtcViewEntity, bool>>(Expression.Not(predicate.Body), predicate.Parameters);
}

// applying generated predicate
queryable = queryable.Where(predicate);
```

Answer (score 0):

my code runs fine if I use EF.Functions directly

```
var result = context.Cars.Where(c => EF.Functions.Like(c.Brand, "%a%")).ToList();
```

also testing with Linqpad and Northwind localDB with a different non-EF  provider.

```
var config = new ParsingConfig { ResolveTypesBySimpleName = true };
var example2 =  from c in Customers
                where SqlMethods.Like(c.City, "[aeiou]%")
                select c;
```

Answer (score -2):

Looks like the errors you are getting have to do with Linq not being
able to "transform" the data so it can parse it or something along
those lines Is it possible for you instead of the "Like" operator you
use the "Contains"?

```
var Something = SomethingElse.Filter(x => x.Argument.Contains(Description));
```

Comment: No, I can't use `Contains()` because the wildcard can be in the middle of the string value.