# Expression.Call on array with a custom function

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, reflection, expression-trees

I have a list of items, I want ,via expression, to filter out the items using my own custom function.

Something like this

`return Items.Where(Foo)`
`private static bool Foo(Item item) { item.Name.Equals("...");`

what i currently have

```
public static Expression BuildExpression(IList<Item> items) 
{
    Expression<Func<Item, bool>> expression = item => Foo(item);
    var method = (expression.Body as MethodCallExpression)?.Method;
    return Expression.Call(method, Expression.Constant(items.First());
}
```

this seems to work find and well for *1* item but i can't figure out how to change it to work for `IList<Item>`

P.s

`Foo` signature can be changed if needed

Comment: `Func<Emitter, bool>` -  what is `Emitter`?

Comment: I have made function which do that [GetItemsPredicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70017345/10646316), check how it fits your needs. It generates predicate based on pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the nutshell you need to find the [`Enumerable.Where<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,Boolean>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-8.0#system-linq-enumerable-where-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-system-boolean)))) method. For example:

```
// find the Enumerable.Where with 2 parameters using reflection
var where = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod(nameof(Enumerable.Where), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static, new[]
{
    typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0)),
    typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(Type.MakeGenericMethodParameter(0), typeof(bool))
});

// make generic Enumerable.Where<Item>
var whereItem = where.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Item));

// sample data 
IList<Item> items = new List<Item> { new() };
// sample filter
var filter = (Item i) => true;

// create expression
var expr = Expression.Call(whereItem, Expression.Constant(items), Expression.Constant(filter));

// validate
var enumerable = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEnumerable<Item>>>(expr).Compile()();
```

[Demo@sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

[Demo@dotnetfiddle.net with .NET Framework 4.7.1](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SvzTZ3), main change:

```
var where = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    .First(mi => mi.Name == "Where" 
          && mi.GetParameters().Length == 2);
```

P.S.

TBH I doubt that this would be very useful for you but without having
full overview of the problem it is hard to tell.

Comment: can you alter your answer to fit NetFramework , sadly MakeGenericMethod is only available from core 2.1

Comment: @styx [`MakeGenericMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod?view=net-8.0) is available since .NET Framework 2.0.  `MakeGenericMethodParameter` is not available for earlier versions. Instead of using it you can use something like `typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods(...).Where(mi => mi.GetParameters().Length == 2).First`

Comment: @styx added demo for .NET Framework.

Comment: Thanks, i wrote it a bit different, but it does the trick

Comment: I want to add an option to negate the whole where clause, to do so i want to pass one more parameter to the `filter` ,how can i do it?  `Expression.Not( Expression.Constant(filter));` throws an exception

Comment: @styx you are trying to generate something like `Func<T, bool> x = ..; ...Where(!x)` which is obviously wrong. If you will a full repro (probably in a new answer) I will try to look later.

Comment: this worked for me`public static Func<T,bool> Negate<T>(this Func<T,bool > func) {
    return t => !func(t);
}`

Comment: @styx yes, this is one way of doing this.