# How to select ID from a DB having a filter with pair values using EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have this class

```
public class Columns
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }
}
```

And I have this list out of the class

```
var listOfColumns = new List<Columns>
{
   new Columns { Name = "ColumnA", TableName = "TableA" },
   new Columns { Name = "ColumnB", TableName = "TableA" },
   new Columns { Name = "ColumnA", TableName = "TableB" },
   new Columns { Name = "ColumnB", TableName = "TableB" },
};
```

I have this DB named DBId with values:

```
   ID   |    Name    |    TableName
  ------+------------+----------------
    1   |   ColumnA  |      TableA
    2   |   ColumnB  |      TableA    
    3   |   ColumnA  |      TableB
    4   |   ColumnB  |      TableB 
    5   |   ColumnA  |      TableC
    6   |   ColumnB  |      TableC
```

How can I get the ID of the column from the DB using the value from listOfColumns with EF Core, ith out using loops and generating a new list?

This code snippet returns an error

```
var newListWithID = _context.DBId
                            .Where(d => listOfColumns.Any(l => l.Name == d.Name 
                                                               && l.TableName == d.TableName))
                            .ToList();
```

Comment: What error does your code return?

Comment: could not be translated

Comment: Use [FilterByItems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67666993/10646316)

Comment: There is no `ID` property in your class, so you can not select it.