# Query where multiple columns have to match a value set simultaneously in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

**The problem**

I have a client application which loads a local data file. This data file specifies for each item the `Type` and `Version`.

From this file, I compile a list of `Type` and `Version` pairs.

```
var typeVersionSets = datafile.Select(item => new { Type = item.TypeId, Version = item.VersionId }).Distinct();
```

*Note*: there are more than these two fields, but for the sake of simplicity I just denote these two.

I also have a SQL Server which runs in the cloud. I need to get all records from a table which meet the value pairs (so the column values must match *simultaneously*).

I wrote this simple query which cannot be run by EF Core:

```
List<MyTableRow> MyResult = await dbContext.MyTable
    .Where(dbItem => typeVersionSets.Contains(new { Type = dbItem.TypeId, Version = dbItem.VersionId }))
    .ToListAsync();
```

I get the following runtime error:

> One or more errors occurred. (The LINQ expression 'DbSet().Where(p => __MyTableRowTypeVersions_2.Contains(new { Type = p.TypeId, Version = p.VersionId }))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.)

**TLDR some details**

The `MyTable` is huge and I cannot afford to download it every time and evaluate the LINQ expression on the client.

The number of `typeVersionSets` is reasonably small (let's say 10 sets).

Of course, I can loop over `typeVersionSets` like:

```
List<MyTableRow> MyResult = new List<MyTableRow>();

foreach (var set in typeVersionSets)
{
    MyResult.AddRange(
            await dbContext.MyTable
                .Where(pp => pp.TypeId == set.Type && pp.VersionId == set.Version)
                .ToListAsync()
            );
}
```

However, this would require 10 database calls.

This code will be executed many times per user and by many users.

Is there a more efficient solution which would result in 1 database call per event without transferring a lot of unnecessary data to the client (or the server).

**Some additional notes**

I use:

- .NET (core) 5.0
- Entity Framework Core version 5.0.9.

In case it matters, I cannot migrate to EF Core 6 since this required a migration to .NET (core) 6.0 which raises a lot of issues which are out of my scope.

Comment: what about executing row sql query - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql, sometimes is better

Comment: @spzvtbg You mean a raw SQL query. I like the idea. It would be very readable. But how to incorporate the (dynamic) data in my C# list `typeVersionSets` in this query. Use a string builder and a loop or is there some nicer way?

Comment: nicer will be using of string.Join(..., instead of looping. unfortunaly ef raw sql do not undersand from collection parameters, i think !?...,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be inclined to build a dynamic `Expression<Func<MyTableRow, bool>>` to represent the filter.

```
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyTableRow), "dbItem");

var parts = new List<Expression>();
foreach (var set in typeVersionSets)
{
    var typeIdValue = Expression.Property(p, nameof(MyTableRow.TypeId));
    var typeIdTarget = Expression.Constant(set.Type);
    var typeIdTest = Expression.Equal(typeIdValue, typeIdTarget);
    
    var versionIdValue = Expression.Property(p, nameof(MyTableRow.VersionId));
    var versionIdTarget = Expression.Constant(set.Version);
    var versionIdTest = Expression.Equal(versionIdValue, versionIdTarget);
    
    var part = Expression.AndAlso(typeIdTest, versionIdTest);
    parts.Add(part);
}

var body = parts.Aggregate(Expression.OrElse);
var filter = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyTableRow, bool>>(body, p);

List<MyTableRow> MyResult = await dbContext.MyTable
    .Where(filter)
    .ToListAsync()
```

[Expression Trees (C#) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/)

Comment: This works, thank you! Although I must say, this is quite complex and therefore somewhat hard to read what is happening. However, it still works!

Comment: What does the magic constant `"dbItem"` actually do in your first line?

Comment: @Stefan It just gives a name to the parameter, in case you want to debug the final expression. It doesn't actually make any difference to the code, and you can omit it if you'd prefer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this [extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67666993/10646316):

```cs
dbContext.MyTable
    .FilterByItems(typeVersionSets, (pp, set) => pp.TypeId == set.Type && pp.VersionId == set.Version, true)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you! Do I understand correctly that, under the hood, this answer is the same Richard Deeming's answer? Only this extension provides a clean concise way of writing the Linq query? I like the readability.

Comment: Exactly. Just makes things easier. You do not need to work with Expressions, function hides that under hood.

Comment: Perfect! This should be a default feature in EF core!