# Filter query by multiple parameters from the list of objects

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core

There's a class that looks like this:

```
class CustomerPurchase {
    int CustomerId;
    int PurchaseId;
    int Cost;
}
```

I've used Code First approach and Entity Framework Core migrations to create the DB.

There's also a filter that looks like this:

```
class Filter {
    int CustomerId;
    int PurchaseId;
}
```

Now, I'm trying to filter the data by pairs of ids.

Here's my code:

```
var filters = new List<Filter>();

ctx.CustomerPurchases
    .Where(p => filters.Any(f => 
        f.CustomerId == p.CustomerId &&
        f.PurchaseId == p.PurchaseId))
    .ToList();
```

Obviously, there is no way this will work. `filters` is the list of objects and it will not be translated into the SQL query.
I'm getting an exception: `The LINQ expression blah could not be translated.`

So, how do I make it work? This particular table contains a few millions of records, so there's no way I can filter it on the client side.

I'm not tied to entity framework: feel free to suggest a different approach, in case there is one.
For obvious reasons, I'm not going to generate a raw query, like `WHERE (CustomerId = {1} AND PurchaseId = {2}) OR ...`. Anything other than that is welcome.

Comment: You can use [this extension FilterByItems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67666993/10646316) to generate desired filter.

Comment: If you don't expect a lot of overlap, you could filter separately by `CustomerId` and `PurchaseId` then switch to client side (`AsEnumerable`) and filter again by the pairs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this issue earlier and here how I fixed it
You have two options in this case

1- Filter based on the ids

```
var res1 = dbcontext.CustomerPurchases
    .Where(p => filters.Select(c=>c.PurchaseId).Contains(p.PurchaseId))
    .Where(p => filters.Select(c => c.CustomerId).Contains(p.CustomerId));
```

2- Use contains

```
var resq = await dbcontext.CustomerPurchases
    .Where(p=> filters.Contains(new Filter { CustomerId = p.CustomerId,PurchaseId = p.PurchaseId }))
    .ToListAsync();
```

but if you run this one you won't get any result unless you implement `IEquatable`

So your `Filter` class will look like this

```
public class Filter : IEquatable<Filter>
{
    public int CustomerId;
    public int PurchaseId;

    public bool Equals(Filter? other)
    {
        return this.PurchaseId == other.PurchaseId &&
            this.CustomerId == other.CustomerId;
    }
}
```

Here is the full code of both ways

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDBContext>()
                  .UseInMemoryDatabase("test")
                  .Options;
var dbcontext = new ApplicationDBContext(options);
await dbcontext.CustomerPurchases.AddAsync(new CustomerPurchase { CustomerId = 1,PurchaseId = 1,Cost = 10 });
await dbcontext.CustomerPurchases.AddAsync(new CustomerPurchase { CustomerId = 1, PurchaseId = 2, Cost = 10 });
await dbcontext.CustomerPurchases.AddAsync(new CustomerPurchase { CustomerId = 1, PurchaseId = 3, Cost = 10 });
await dbcontext.CustomerPurchases.AddAsync(new CustomerPurchase { CustomerId = 2, PurchaseId = 2, Cost = 10 });
await dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();

var filters = new List<Filter>();
filters.Add(new Filter { CustomerId = 1, PurchaseId = 2 });
filters.Add(new Filter { CustomerId = 2, PurchaseId = 2 });

var resq = await dbcontext.CustomerPurchases
    .Where(p=> filters.Contains(new Filter { CustomerId = p.CustomerId,PurchaseId = p.PurchaseId }))
    .ToListAsync();
foreach (var item in resq)
{
    Console.WriteLine($" CustomerId : {item.CustomerId} , PurchaseId : {item.PurchaseId} Cost : {item.Cost}");
}

var res1 = dbcontext.CustomerPurchases
    .Where(p => filters.Select(c=>c.PurchaseId).Contains(p.PurchaseId))
    .Where(p => filters.Select(c => c.CustomerId).Contains(p.CustomerId));

var res = await res1.ToListAsync();
Console.WriteLine("===========================================================");
foreach (var item in res)
{
    Console.WriteLine($" CustomerId : {item.CustomerId} , PurchaseId : {item.PurchaseId} Cost : {item.Cost}");
}
```

and the running code
[image]

**Update**
After changed to SQL server I still got the error so option 2 is not an option when running on SQL server

But I found another solution where I am able to build the where clause based on the list of filters that I have
I found this [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)
and here is the code using predicate builder

```
var whereclause = PredicateBuilder.False<CustomerPurchase>();
foreach (var filterrow in filters)
{

    whereclause = whereclause.Or(c => c.CustomerId == filterrow.CustomerId && c.PurchaseId == filterrow.PurchaseId);
    
}
var resqq = dbcontext.CustomerPurchases.Where(whereclause);

var resq = await resqq.ToListAsync();
foreach (var item in resq)
{
    Console.WriteLine($" CustomerId : {item.CustomerId} , PurchaseId : {item.PurchaseId} Cost : {item.Cost}");
}
```

That will build the query which will be translated by sql to the following statement

```
DECLARE @__filterrow_CustomerId_0 int = 1;
DECLARE @__filterrow_PurchaseId_1 int = 2;
DECLARE @__filterrow_CustomerId_2 int = 2;
DECLARE @__filterrow_PurchaseId_3 int = 2;

SELECT [c].[PurchaseId], [c].[CustomerId]
FROM [dbo].[CustomerPurchase] AS [c]
WHERE (([c].[CustomerId] = @__filterrow_CustomerId_0) AND ([c].[PurchaseId] = @__filterrow_PurchaseId_1)) 
    OR 
    (([c].[CustomerId] = @__filterrow_CustomerId_2) AND ([c].[PurchaseId] = @__filterrow_PurchaseId_3))
```

Here is the full class of PredicateBuyilder

```
public static class PredicateBuilder
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return f => true; }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return f => false; }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
              (Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
                                                         Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
              (Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }
}
```

**I hope that answer your question !!**

Comment: At least in EF Core, your second method won't work: EF can't translate `IEquatable` or `Filter` to SQL. And your first method is incomplete - you will return undesired results.

Comment: @NetMage I am using EF core in memory, and it works fine , I agree with you the first option might return undesired data but the second option is working for me , Maybe I should try in on SQL and update

Comment: When I test in SQL I get could not be translated.

Comment: Thanks, man! Sadly, there's no way the 2nd method will be translated to SQL. The 1st one looks fine, but it might result in getting some extra data. It's still better than filtering only by 1 parameter, though. I guess I'll have to get my hands dirty and write the SQL query manually after all.

Comment: @HirasawaYui thanks for the feedback I will try to find work around for the SQL , good luck

Comment: @HirasawaYui you can add AsEnumerable() to  dbcontext.CustomerPurchases but this will be very bad for performance but it won't give you any errors

Comment: Yeah, I wish I could just add `AsEnumerable()`. In real life that `CustomerPurchases` table contains over 10Gb of data, so it'll take like 3 hours to just pull the data.

Comment: @HirasawaYui Check my update on the main answer , I tested it with sql server and actually works fine, it just build the where clause from the given filter list