# C# EF Core - Query must contains all in the List<object>

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

```
class OrderItem
{
  public long Id,
  public int Qty,
  public long ProductId
}

class Order
{
  public long Id
  public ICollectable<OrderItem> Items = new List<OrderItem>
}

var dtos = new List<ItemDTO>
{
  new ItemDTO { ProductId = 1, Qty = 2 },
  new ItemDTO { ProductId = 1, Qty = 1 }
};

var orders = await _context.Orders
    .Where(_ => _.Items.Any(i => dtos.All(dto => dto.ProductId == i.ProductId && dto.Qty <= i.Qty)));
```

How to query every `Order` that **match the conditions** of all items in `dtos` from its `Items` list?

I cannot use `.All()` with complex object in Entity Framework.

Comment: Sorry but why duplicate the same code and question twice?

Comment: One straightforward solution I can come up with is using `PredicateBuilder` from `LinqKit`, then enumerate through `dtos` while building predicate with `.Or()`, then use it in the `Where()`. But it depends on if you can use the library.

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang my skill has not been at there yet. And i want to query all the dto at once, not each of the dto

Comment: If `dtos` contains 2 dto, 1 with `{ProductId = 1}` , 1 with `{ProductId = 2}` , nothing will match because `Order` must match all items in `dtos` . Do I understand this correct?

Comment: Use RawSQL with entity : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity framework core add multible where as OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71661316/entity-framework-core-add-multible-where-as-or)

Comment: @XiangWeiHuang yes Order must match all items in `dtos`. Btw I solved it by chaining `AND WHERE` with `foreach`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by building `Where` queries.

It will populate many `AND` chain.

```
var whereQuery = _context.Orders.AsQueryable();

foreach(var dto in dtos)
{
  whereQuery = whereQuery.Where(x => x.Items.Any(i => i.productId == dto.productId && i.Qty >= dto.Qty);
}

var result = await whereQuery.ToListAsync();
```