# Linq query to retrieve data from SQL table (using Entity Framework Core) that matches the list of object List<BucketList>

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

```
public class Table1EntityClass
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class BucketList 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

I need to get data from table1 where name, price, category in `List<BucketList>` matches the row where this combination is present.

For example

```
'Name- Apple, Description = 'A fruit', Price- 30, category - fruits, Quantity - 10'
'Name- Apple, Description = 'A fruit', Price- 20, category - fruits, Quantity - 10'
'Name- Orange, Description = 'A fruit', Price- 50, category - fruits, Quantity - 10'
'Name- banana, Description = 'A fruit', Price- 30, category - fruits, Quantity - 10'
'Name- Onion, Description = 'A vegetable', Price - 30, category - vegetable, quantity - 5'
```

and `List<BucketList>` contains 2 objects:

```
Apple, 30, fruits
Onion, 30, vegetable
```

BucketList declaration in the method :
[method declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoWDO.png)

I want to receive data matching each list of object from table i.e., query should return  1st and 5th row data.

I tried this query:

```
var result = dbContext.table1
                      .Where(item => bucketLists.Any(bucketvalue =>
                                         item.Name == bucketvalue.Name  &&
                                         item.Price == bucketvalue.Price &&
                                         item.Category == bucketvalue.Category))
                      .ToList();
```

But I get an error message that the LINQ query cannot be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Show your declaration for `bucketLists`. Try `dbContext.BucketLists` instead.

Comment: @JonathanWood `List<BucketList> bucketLists` is actually received in a method from an API

Comment: @JonathanWood shouldn't dbContext be done on the table entity class instead of bucket lists

Comment: How big is `bucketLists`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity framework core add multible where as OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71661316/entity-framework-core-add-multible-where-as-or)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, List will be have a large count. Hence I want to limit the database calls.

Comment: How many elements? Do you ready to use third party extensions?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv million records and probably no third party extention but can consider. Can you share any?

Comment: With million records you have to work with temporary tables. What is intention to make such query? UPSERT records, sync databases?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv requirement is to get data for moving to production. With temporary tables, should I just create SP and send a Datatable as input to it? Also, I read somewhere EntityFrameCore.MemoryJoin can be used when working with lists. Any thoughts on performance?

Comment: Forgot about temporary tables right now. *requirement is to get data for moving to production* - how do you plan *move to production*?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv basically need to gather some data from database first through api, based on certain criteria. and later it will be processed according.

Answer (score 0):

*On further research I have determined that the expression tree generated by the `FilterByItems` extension function will yield an optimum query that will perform an index seek, provided an appropriate index is defined.*

*I therefore recommend that approach rather than the answer below. I leave this up just for reference.*

**If** the `bucketlists` count is expected to be **small** (only a few elements) you may be able to use `.SelectMany()` to individually query the matching `table1` rows.

```
var result = bucketLists
    .SelectMany(bucketvalue =>
        dbContext.table1
        .Where(item => item.Name == bucketvalue.Name
                       && item.Price == bucketvalue.Price
                       && item.Category == bucketvalue.Category)
    )
    .DistinctBy(item => item.itemId)
    .ToList();
```

Although this may make several trips to the database, the absence of an "OR" condition should allow for more efficient index usage. (This assumes that `table1` has an index on some permutation of `(Name, Price, Category)`.)

The `.DistinctBy()` is needed if there is the potential for a `table1` row matching more than one `bucketLists` value.

Comment: "Nice" solution, `bucketvalue.Count` queries.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv - I qualified that in my writeup.  The OP stated that bucketLists was an API input (which I interpret as an in-memory collection). For a small number number of bucketlists items, I would rather have a couple of queries that perform index seeks than a constructed condition (expression tree) that includes OR conditions where the generated query is not *sargable* and therefore requires a table scan. That's the tradeoff.  If there were a way to populate a Values subselect that joins to table1, a single sargable query would be possible, but I am not aware of a way to do that.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv - Okay I stand corrected in my assumptions about OR conditions and table scans. It appears that if a series of OR conditions are properly structured so that they can each be handled by the same index, the execution plan will perform an index seek. (Only if that pattern is not matched, the execution plan will fall back to a table scan.) The query optimizer is smarter than I had given it credit for. [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OlKmHw2Y).

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, Can we use Expression tree builder. Any example for the same?

Comment: @Pratyaksh, i have marked in duplicate exactly tree builder.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to work with millions records in list, you should copy this list to database and store in temporary table.
Then you can join to this temporary table and grab only needed records.

You can do that with extension [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) (note that I'm one of the creators)

```cs
using var db = dbContext.CreateLinqToDBConnection(); // create linq2db connection from context

using var tempTable = db.CreateTempTable(bucketLists); // create and fill temporary table using BulkCopy

var query = 
    from tmp in tempTable
    from t in dbContext.table1.Where(t => t.Name == tmp.Name && t.Price == tmp.Price && t.Category == tmp.Category) // join to temp table
    select t;

var result = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing that. Also how it would be performance wise if I create an SP and input to it a DataTable type and then perform a join. In that way, Query will run on Db and return only required data.

Comment: Probably performance will be a little bit better. Let me know how many efforts you have spent on this solution.