# How to programmatically add JOINs to query from list using EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I am trying to query data from database using EF Core, but the scenery is a bit complicated for me. I will try to be clear and synthesize what I want to accomplish.

There are three tables involved:

- Table WORK_TO_DO - Columns: ID, DESCRIPTION
- Table PARAM_DEFINITIONS_FOR_WORK - Columns: ID, NAME
- Table PARAM_VALUES_FOR_WORK - Columns: WORK_TO_DO_ID, PARAM_DEFINITION_ID, VALUE

Let's say these tables have their classes as below.

```
public class WorkToDo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class ParamDefinition
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ParamValue
{
    public int WorkToDoId { get; set; }
    public int ParamDefinitionId { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of ParamValue items with ParamDefinitionId and Value populated, but without WorkToDoId.

I want to query all WorkToDo items that match the ParamValue items, considering **all** the ParamValue items and not just any of them.

Let me explain with example records on each table:

WORK_TO_DO

| ID | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Work Example A |
| 2 | Work Example B |

PARAM_DEFINITIONS_FOR_WORK

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | Param Definition X |
| 102 | Param Definition Y |
| 103 | Param Definition W |
| 104 | Param Definition Z |
| 105 | Param Definition + |

PARAM_VALUES_FOR_WORK

| WORK_TO_DO_ID | PARAM_DEFINITION_ID | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | Param Value J |
| 1 | 102 | Param Value K |
| 2 | 103 | Param Value L |
| 2 | 104 | Param Value M |
| 2 | 105 | Param Value N |

So, let's say my list of ParamValues has two items: `ParamDefinitionId = 101, Value = "Param Value J"` and `ParamDefinitionId = 102, Value = "Param Value K"`. I would like to retrieve the WorkToDo of Id = 1.

If my list of ParamValues had, instead, three items:

- `ParamDefinitionId = 103, Value = "Param Value L"`
- `ParamDefinitionId = 104, Value = "Param Value M"`
- `ParamDefinitionId = 105, Value = "Param Value N"`

Then I would like my query to retrieve the WorkToDo of Id = 2.

Note that the size of ParamValues list is variable!

I'd like to say that I have tried a solution, but the truth is I don't even know how to begin. I've searched on the web but had no luck.

I only have an idea of how I would do this using SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT WORK_TO_DO.ID, WORK_TO_DO.DESCRIPTION
FROM WORK_TO_DO
INNER JOIN PARAM_VALUES_FOR_WORK PV1 ON PV1.WORK_TO_DO_ID = WORK_TO_DO.ID
INNER JOIN PARAM_VALUES_FOR_WORK PV2 ON PV2.WORK_TO_DO_ID = WORK_TO_DO.ID
(... Adding as many INNER JOINs as needed based on list of ParamValues)
INNER JOIN PARAM_VALUES_FOR_WORK PVX ON PVX.WORK_TO_DO_ID = WORK_TO_DO.ID
WHERE PV1.PARAM_DEFINITION_ID = :ParamValues[0].ParamDefinitionId
  AND PV1.VALUE = :ParamValues[0].Value
  AND PV2.PARAM_DEFINITION_ID = :ParamValues[1].ParamDefinitionId
  AND PV2.VALUE = :ParamValues[1].Value
  (... Adding as many conditions as needed based on list of ParamValues)
  AND PVX.PARAM_DEFINITION_ID = :ParamValues[X].ParamDefinitionId
  AND PVX.VALUE = :ParamValues[X].Value
```

Basically I want to add JOINs and filters to the query based on my list of ParamValues. How can I do this?

Comment: Why not just put navigation props on your entities and then query them starting from ParamValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [FilterByItems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67666649/lambda-linq-with-contains-criteria-for-multiple-keywords/67666993#67666993) extension and you can generate desired query:

```cs
var requiredCount = ParamValues.Count();

var query = context.WorkToDo
    .Where(w => context.ParamValue
        .Where(pv = pv.WorkToDoId == w.Id)
        .FilterByItems(ParamValues, (pv, v) => pv.ParamDefinitionId == v.ParamDefinitionId && pv.Value == v.Name, true)
        .Count() >= requiredCount
    );
```

Comment: I accepted your answer as useful although I am not willing to use it. Looks like it will do the job - if I changed the last parameter of FilterByItems() to "false" - but seems too complicated, possibly making it hard to maintain. For now I got it to work using Raw SQL. Thank you!!

Comment: I do not understand phrase **hard to maintain**? Hard to maintain is the SQL.