# Entity Framework Core: the query can't be translated. How to know if a record contains a string from a list of strings

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am trying to know if a property of an entity contains any of the string in a list of strings.

I am trying to do this:

```cs
List<string> miLstStrings;   // it is populated with some strings.

List<Data> miLstResultDb = await miDbContext.Data
    .Where(x => miLstStrings.Any(y => x.StringProperty.Contains(y)))
    .ToListAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

But I get an error telling me that the query can't be translated.

Thanks.

Comment: EF Core has limited support for local collections and you have to build Expression Tree dynamically to make desired filter. You can use this extension [FilterByItems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67666993/10646316) and replace `Where` with `.FilterByItems(miLstStrings, (x, s) => x.StringProperty.Contains(s), true)`

Comment: And does this allow to evalute the query in the server instead of the client?

Comment: Actually it is main goal why this function is born - generate Expression Tree which will be executed on the server side.