# EF Linq query to check elements from list inside list with multiple properties

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to write a Linq query that will translate to SQL to get existing record based on provided lists.

searchRequest is a list of:

```
class SearchRequestDTO
    {
        public string Book { get; set; }
        public string Page { get; set; }
        public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

This is my initial idea:

```cs
var documentNumbersFlat = new HashSet<string>(searchRequest.Select(d => d.DocumentNumber));
var books = new HashSet<string>(searchRequest.Select(d => d.Book));
var pages = new HashSet<string>(searchRequest.Select(d => d.Page));

var queryable = _dbSet.Include(i => i.Searches).Where(a =>
    a.Searches.Count == searchRequest.Count &&
    a.Searches.All(i => documentNumbersFlat.Contains(i.DocumentNumber) || (books.Contains(i.Book) && pages.Contains(i.Page))));
```

But I dont think it is correct because I want exact Book and Page and in this case Im checking two separate list, so ideally I wanted to have something like that:

```cs
a.Searches.All(i => searchRequest.Contains(new {i.DocumentNumber, i.Book, i.Page)));
```

Alternative (like a last resort):

```cs
var documentNumbersFlat = new HashSet<string>(searchRequest.Select(d => d.DocumentNumber));
var books = new HashSet<string>(searchRequest.Select(d => $"{d.Book}_{d.Page}"));

var queryable = _dbSet.Where(a =>
    a.Searches.Count == searchRequest.Count &&
    a.Searches.All(i => documentNumbersFlat.Contains(i.DocumentNumber) || books.Contains($"{i.Book}_{i.Page}")));
```

Additionally I want to point out I`m looking for best way of handling it in terms of performance.

All suggestions appreciated:)

Comment: Show class definition for `searchRequest` elements.

Comment: Please add a tag for the Entity Framework version you use.

Comment: Check this function [FilterByItems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67666993/10646316). It will generate needed predicate.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv searchRequest class definition added

Comment: @GertArnold 3.1.26 latest for .net core 3.1