# Entity Framework Linq Where condition With Any/All

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Using the below code, I'm Attempting to get a list of items which is in price range by Linq

```
public Task<List<Item>> GetFilteredItems(List<Tuple<decimal, decimal>> priceList)
{
    var itemList = from i in _dbTable
                   where (priceList.Count() == 0 || (priceList.All(x => i.MRP >= x.Item1) && priceList.All(x => i.MRP <= x.Item2)))
                   select i;

    return Task.FromResult(itemList.Cast<Item>().ToList());
}
```

But Getting an error

```
Error creating query string: The LINQ expression 'x => EntityShaperExpression: 
    GiftCartBO.Entities.ItemTBL
    ValueBufferExpression: 
        ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
    IsNullable: False
.MRP >= x.Item1' could not be translated. 
Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or 
switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 
'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. 
See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information..
```

Comment: If MRP has to be greater than all of x.Item1 (and less than all of item2), I think you can get a bit creative and simply do two single comparisons: one between `i.MRP` and the **max** of item1 and the other between `i.MRP` and the **min** of item2.  You will also get a faster query as a bonus.

Comment: @RobertHarvey i think you should write the code and post the answer

Comment: Get this extension [FilterByItems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67666993/10646316) and you can do the following: `_dbTable.FilterByItems(priceList, (i, p) => i.MRP >= p.Item1 && i.MRP <= p.Item2, true)`. Function will generate needed predicate.

Comment: Pricelist Can be 0-500 and 1000-2000. This case i no need 501-999 mrp items. So this won't helpful

Answer (score 1):

EF internally convert your `LINQ` query to `SQL` query. And sometimes all part of your `LINQ` query can not be converted to `SQL` so it will raise **runtime error**. Same happen with you as well. EF will not be able to convert `List<Tuple<decimal, decimal>>` object for `SQL` query. And same thing is mentioned in error message and link provided in error message https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038.

You can fetch all data at once and they you apply your `LINQ` query like below.

```
var itemList = _dbTable.ToList()
                .Where(i => priceList.Count() == 0 || (priceList.All(x => i.MRP >= x.Item1) && priceList.All(x => i.MRP <= x.Item2)));

return Task.FromResult(itemList.Cast<Item>().ToList());
```

If you find above query returns correct result then you should improve your code as suggested by @Robert Harvey in comment. You can fetch `max` value of `item1` & `min` value of `item2` and use it instead. Complete code cab be like below.

```
if (priceList.Count() == 0)
{
    var itemList = _dbTable.ToList();
    
    return Task.FromResult(itemList.Cast<Item>().ToList());
}
else
{
    var maxItem1 = priceList.Max(x => x.item1);
    var minItem2 = priceList.Min(x => x.item2);
    var itemList = _dbTable.ToList()
                .Where(i => i.MRP >= maxItem1 && i.MRP <= minItem2);
    
    return Task.FromResult(itemList.Cast<Item>().ToList());
}
```

---

I believe you want to fetch all records whose price fall between any one of the value from `priceList`. Then you need to update your query like below.

```
var itemList = _dbTable.ToList()
                .Where(i => priceList.Count() == 0 || priceList.Any(x => i.MRP >= x.Item1 && i.MRP <= x.Item2));

return Task.FromResult(itemList.Cast<Item>().ToList());
```

Comment: well that's slow and memory inefficient

Comment: Hi @theemee, Thanks for suggestion. I've improved the answer.

Comment: Pricelist Can be 0-500 and 1000-2000. This case i no need 501-999 mrp items. So this won't helpful