# How to filter child table by dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a question for you all!!!,

Assume that I have 2 tables, one of them is a parent, and the other is a child. I want to filter the parent table by sending data from the child object. The child table contains 4 columns like

> {Id, RuleId, RuleKey, RuleValue}

I send a dictionary as a request that includes value for 2 columns ( RuleKey, RuleValue) of the child object.  I want to return the parent object that includes RuleKey and RuleValue I sent.

```cs
// Key is the column name of the child table and value is the corresponding value
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>()
{
    {"RuleKey", "RuleValue"},
    {"RuleKey1", "RuleValue1"}
}
```

This is what I tried but it obviously won't work and still give the syntax error.
These 2 questions about this issue;

1-) How should I do this (Important one:))))) 
2-) Will be there any error If I do this In-Memory, If I remember that correctly, EFCore won't translate the LINQ to SQL script because of the memory issues.

```cs
var rules = _ruleContext.Rules.AsQueryable();
rules = rules.Where(u => u.Criteria.Where(k => dictionary.Keys.Contains(k.Key) && dictionary.Values.Contains(k.Value)));
```

```
public class Rule : Entity<int>
{
    public string RuleName { get; set; }
    public string Expression { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Criteria> Criteria { get; set; }
}

public class Criteria : Entity<int>
{
    public int RuleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public Rule Rule { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you show `Rule` and `Criteria` model classes? Do you need as result `rule` which meets all `dictionary` criteria?

Comment: I added class you requested, also the answer is yes. I want to rules list as a result that includes all criteria. @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function [FilterByItems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67666993/10646316) (don't want to repeat myself). Then query can be written in the following way:

```cs
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>()
{
    {"RuleKey", "RuleValue"},
    {"RuleKey1", "RuleValue1"}
}

var matched = _ruleContext.Criterias
    .FilterByItems(dictionary, (c, kv) => c.Key == kv.Key && c.Value == kv.Value, true)
    .GroupBy(c => c.RuleId)
    .Where(g => g.Count() == dictionary.Count)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        RuleId = g.Key,
    });

var rules =
    from r in _ruleContext.Rules
    join m in matched on r.Id equals m.RuleId
    select r;

var result = rules.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you want to only match criteria where both `Key` and `Value` match a key/value pair in the dictionary. (Your pseudocode would include any rules where either the key or value matched)

What you're trying to do is join between the `Criteria` table and the key/values in the dictionary. One way to accomplish this would be to create a temporary table containing those pairs, and then use a raw SQL statement to join from `Criteria` onto that.

Something like this might work:

```cs
// To use the temporary table you need to make sure that the connection stays 
// open beyond the table creation statement
context.Database.OpenConnection();
try
{
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("CREATE TABLE #RequiredCriteria ([Value] nvarchar(100), [Key] nvarchar(100))");
    
    // If you're expecting LOTs of criteria this could become a bottleneck...
    foreach (var criteria in dictionary)
    {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated($"INSERT INTO #RequiredCriteria ([Value], [Key]) VALUES ({criteria.Key}, {criteria.Value})");
    }

    // This creates Rule objects from a raw SQL query that does 
    // the required joining of parameters
    var matched = context.Rules.FromSqlRaw(
        @"SELECT * FROM Rules 
        WHERE Id IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT RuleId 
            FROM Criteria C 
                INNER JOIN #RequiredCriteria RC 
                    ON C.[Key] = RC.[Key] AND C.[Value] = RC.[Value])")
        .ToList();

    context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("DROP TABLE #RequiredCriteria");
}
finally
{
    context.Database.CloseConnection();
}
```

**Edit (now without distinct):**

I noticed in your comment that a rule must meet *all* the given criteria - this version of the query will make sure that any matching rule will have the same number of **distinct** criteria that were requested. That way if the same criteria key and value is duplicated in the request it won't matter:

```cs
// To use the temporary table you need to make sure that the connection stays 
// open beyond the table creation statement
context.Database.OpenConnection();
try
{
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("CREATE TABLE #RequiredCriteria ([Value] nvarchar(100), [Key] nvarchar(100))");
    
    // If you're expecting LOTs of criteria this could become a bottleneck...
    foreach (var item in dictionary)
    {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated($"INSERT INTO #RequiredCriteria ([Value], [Key]) VALUES ({item.Key}, {item.Value})");
    }

    var matched = context.Rules.FromSqlInterpolated(
        @$"SELECT * FROM Rules 
        WHERE Id IN (
            SELECT RuleId 
            FROM Criteria C 
                INNER JOIN #RequiredCriteria RC 
                    ON C.[Key] = RC.[Key] AND C.[Value] = RC.[Value]
            GROUP BY RuleId
            HAVING COUNT(RuleId) = {dictionary.Count}
        )")
        .ToList();

    context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("DROP TABLE #RequiredCriteria");
}
finally
{
    context.Database.CloseConnection();
}
```

**Edit 2:**

If the `Criteria` table is going to be quite large, I'd definitely recommend you have an index on the `Key` and `Value` columns, otherwise you'll be doing a clustered index scan across the entire table for every query.

Comment: Right solution via raw SQL. But you can omit Distinct, in Dictionary it is required unique Key.