# How to iterate over a list to build a Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following working query:

```
posts.Where(post =>
    post.Fields
        .Where(x =>
            x.RegionId == "RecipeArticleDetails" &&
            (x.FieldId == "RecipePrepTime" || x.FieldId == "RecipeCookTime")
        )
        .GroupBy(x => x.PostId)
        .Select(x => new { ID = x.Key, Value = x.Sum(y => Convert.ToInt32(y.Value)) })
        .Where(x => x.Value > 10 && x.Value < 40)
        .Any()
)
List<string> suppliedTimes = new List<string>(){
    "10-60","0-10"
};
```

I would like to replace `Where(x => x.Value > 10 && x.Value < 40)` so it looks up from a list of ranges:

```
List<string> suppliedTimes = new List<string>(){
    "10-60","0-10"
};
```

My understanding is I can use select to iterate over the items:

```
posts.Where(post =>
    suppliedTimes.Select(x => new {low = Convert.ToInt32(x.Split("-",StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]), high = Convert.ToInt32(x.Split("-",StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1]) })
    .Any( a =>
        post.Fields
            .Where(x =>
                x.RegionId == "RecipeArticleDetails" &&
                (x.FieldId == "RecipePrepTime" || x.FieldId == "RecipeCookTime")
            )
            .GroupBy(x => x.PostId)
            .Select(x => new { ID = x.Key, Value = x.Sum(y => Convert.ToInt32(y.Value)) })
            .Where(x => x.Value > a.low && x.Value < a.high)
            .Any()
        )
)
```

However this code results in the error:

> could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Please can someone explain how I can achieve this and why what I have isn't working.

Comment: Which EF version. It looks like EF Core, but tag is marked as EF 6.

Comment: Anyway EF any versions supports only `Contains` or very simple `Any` with local collections.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv it's EF Core. Is it possible with this version?

Comment: Everything is possible, but it may need additional efforts.  Will prepare sample how to do that.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Many thanks! I would be very interested to see how this is done. I've just been reading about supported methods and they seem to be supported: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities?redirectedfrom=MSDN&WT.mc_id=email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work with EF Core I would suggest my extnsion [FilterByItems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67666993/10646316) and change the way how to retrieve records.

```cs
List<string> suppliedTimes = new List<string>(){
    "10-60","0-10"
};

var ranges = suppliedTimes
    .Select(x => x.Split("-", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    .Select(x => new {
        low = Convert.ToInt32(x[0]), 
        high = Convert.ToInt32(x[1]) 
    });
    
var fields = context.Fields
    .Where(x =>
        x.RegionId == "RecipeArticleDetails" &&
        (x.FieldId == "RecipePrepTime" || x.FieldId == "RecipeCookTime")
    )
    .GroupBy(x => x.PostId)
    .Select(x => new { ID = x.Key, Value = x.Sum(y => Convert.ToInt32(y.Value)) })
    .FilterByItems(ranges, (e, r) => e.Value > r.low && e.Value < r.high, true);

var posts = posts
    .Join(fields, p => p.Id, f => f.ID, (p, f) => p);
```

Comment: Thats worked, sincere thanks! I would have prefered to achieve this without an extension method, but have been trying to figure this out for long enough! Do you know what was causing the select to fail and produce that error? Is it just that what I was trying to achieve is unsupported in EF core? It seems to me like it should have worked.

Comment: Answer is obvious, EF Core supports ONLY `Contains` with local collection. I have created such extension method to solve repetitive questions on SO. It produces effective SQL and reduces amount of code needed for such operations.