# EF.Function.Like could not be translated when using List of conditions

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using EF.Core and want to filter by list of strings.

```
var prefixes = new List<string> { "sth", "sth2", "sth3" }


var query = context.Person
            .Where(prefixes.Any(p => EF.Functions.Like(person.Name, p +"%"))
            .Select ...
```

return error, that query could not be translated.

I would like to ask, how this problem can be resolved?

I do not want to filter this in memory, after executing query.

Thank you

Comment: EF supports only `Contains` with local collections. But you can use extension method [FilterByItems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67666993/10646316) - `context.Person.FilterByItems(prefixes, (person, p) => EF.Functions.Like(person.Name, p + "%"), true)`

Comment: But in this case better to use `person.Name.StartsWith(p)`

Comment: Bu person.Name.StartsWith(p) returns error too

Comment: I'll repeat again: **EF supports only Contains with local collections**. Use my extension method which I have created for this frequently asked question. But instead of `Like` use `StartsWith` when using extension `FilterByItems`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, EF core is still rather limited at translating `Any` or `All` to `EXISTS`. You could rewrite your query as a chain of `OR` statements (disjunctions), however this is something rather difficult with Linq.

If including a package is okay, consider `LinqKit`. It provides a `PredicateBuilder`, which you can use this way:

```
var query = context.Person;

var disjunctionPredicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Person>();
foreach (var eachPrefix in prefixes)
{
    // I am using Contains for LIKE, but EF.Functions.Like probably works, too
    disjunctionPredicate = disjunctionPredicate.Or(p => p.Name.Contains(eachPrefix));
}

var result = await query.Where(disjunctionPredicate).ToListAsync();
```

---

A theoretical approach would be to create the `Or` chain functionally:

```
var query = context.Person;

Func<Person, bool> disjunctionPredicate = _ => false;
foreach (var eachPrefix in prefixes)
{
    var oldPredicate = disjunctionPredicate;
    disjunctionPredicate = p => oldPredicate(p) || p.Name.Contains(eachPrefix);
}

var result = await query.Where(disjunctionPredicate).ToListAsync();
```

This works nicely with in-memory collections.
The issues you'll likely run into are, that EF needs `Expression`s instead of `Func`s, and it won't be able to translate the `Invoke` operation (`oldPredicate(p)`). You would have to 'expand' your expression tree afterwards, which is a nightmare - this is why `LinqKit` is so great.

Comment: *Unfortunately, EF core is still rather limited at translating Any or All to EXISTS* - that's wrong. EF Core cannot translate these operators when they are applied to local collection.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv This is effectively the same thing. Entity Framework 6 under .NET Framework had no issue with that. And there are many other cases than this one, where EF core has problems with these operators.

Comment: It is not the same things. In SQL it should be `SELECT * FROM (VALUES(...)) WHERE ...`. EF do not generate this construction.

Comment: I meant you saying that "EF Core cannot translate these operators" here is the same thing as saying it's rather limited. Please don't twist my words around.