# How to find List<string> in a string field in an IQueryable<Entity> in EF with C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, linq

I'm using .Net 6 and EF Core 6.
Suppose that I have an entity which is included a string property and I have a dynamic list of string variables which I want to use LINQ to find out which records of my table specific column included at least one of those words.

**My entity is:**

```
Public class Sample
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}
```

The list of string words is:

```
List<string> words;
```

I'm using this code to reach the result:

```
var query = _sampleRepository.AsQueryable().AsNoTracking(); // the type is IQueryable<Sample>

query = query.Where(x => words.Any(word => x.Caption.Contains(word)));

query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Skip(50).Take(20);

query = query.ToList();
```

But while executing the above code, I would get an *Exception* which is saying that the part of code of :

> query.Where(x => words.Any(word => x.Caption.Contains(word))) could
> not be translated by EF to such a query to get data from Database!

I actually want want and I should use LINQ to do this and it's not possible to use for example `connection.QuerySingleOrDefaultAsync` method or etc.

Please help me do that!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lambda/Linq with Contains criteria for multiple keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67666649/lambda-linq-with-contains-criteria-for-multiple-keywords)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution!

I should using the **Nuget Package** of **`LinqKit`** to help me do that!

This is the solution code:

```
var pb = PredicateBuilder.New<Sample>();
foreach (var word in words)
{
    pb = pb.Or(x => x.Caption.Contains(word));
}
query = query.Where(pb);
```

I needed LinqKit to use **PredicateBuilder** and the above code should be replaced with the `query = query.Where(x => words.Any(word => x.Caption.Contains(word)));` and it worked for me!