# Linq query filter with "contains" with list<T> multiple elements

Tags: linq, list, contains

I want to query a list by Linq but filter by an other list containing two elements ( Name, Status) in my example.
This is inspired by an old question  I've adapted to my issue.
[LINQ: "contains" and a Lambda query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566439/linq-contains-and-a-lambda-query)
(in this answer it's working for only one element i.e. Status)

I try to use the "contains" method but didn't succeed to filter my list.

I should obtain a result with only two  buildings (two, five)
Has anyone an idea where I'm stopped ?

Thanks

> Blockquote

```
    public class Building
    {
        public enum StatusType
        {
            open,
            closed,
            weird,
        };

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public StatusType Status { get; set; }
    }

    private static readonly List<Building> BuildingList = new List<Building>()
    {
        new Building() {Name = "one", Status = Building.StatusType.open},
        new Building() {Name = "two", Status = Building.StatusType.closed},
        new Building() {Name = "three", Status = Building.StatusType.weird},
        new Building() {Name = "four", Status = Building.StatusType.open},
        new Building() {Name = "five", Status = Building.StatusType.closed},
        new Building() {Name = "six", Status = Building.StatusType.weird},
    };

    private  void GetResult()
    {
        var buildingSelect = new List<Building>
        {
            new Building() {Name = "two", Status = Building.StatusType.closed},
            new Building() {Name = "five", Status = Building.StatusType.closed}
        };

        var q = (from building in BuildingList
            where buildingSelect.Contains(building.Name, building.Status)
            select building).ToList();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = q;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem of your LINQ is that you are trying the compare the equality of two `Building`s, which LINQ can only compare by their references because `Building` does not implement `IEquatable<Building>` nor override `object.Equals`.

One way to solve it is to manually specify which properties to compare for equality as per @Wayne's answer.

The other way is, if `Building` instances are meant to be equated by their values and not by their references, implement `IEquatable<Building>` and override `object.Equals`:

```
public class Building : IEquatable<Building>
{
    public Building(string name, StatusType status)
    {
        Name = name;
        Status = status;
    }

    public enum StatusType
    {
        open,
        closed,
        weird,
    };

    public string Name { get; }

    public StatusType Status { get; }

    public static bool operator ==(Building left, Building right)
        => Equals(left, right);

    public static bool operator !=(Building left, Building right)
        => !Equals(left, right);

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as Building);

    public bool Equals(Building other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (ReferenceEquals(other, null) || GetType() != other.GetType())
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Name == other.Name && Status == other.Status;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 23 + Name?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;
            hash = hash * 23 + Status.GetHashCode();
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

That way, your original code would work because `List.Contains` will now use your implementation of `IEquatable<Building>` to check for equality.

Comment: Thanks rexcfnghk, with this I've learned and experimented IEquatable implementation. Contains is now working  with some slight updates in my original code  >  'where buildingSelect.Contains(new Building(building.Name, building.Status))' .  Remove in the list is also working. Great. Many thanks.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
    var q = from b in BuildingList
        from bs in buildingSelect
        where b.Name == bs.Name && b.Status == bs.Status
        select b;
```

or perhaps:

```
    var q = from b in BuildingList
        join bs in buildingSelect
        on new { b.Name, b.Status } equals new { bs.Name, bs.Status }
        select b;
```

Comment: I've just a problem left as I need to  modify the buildingSelect list by removing some  lines like this : 'code  buildingSelect.Remove(new Building()
            {Name = "two", Status = Building.StatusType.closed}); ' This doesn't work. Any idea to correct this. Regards.

Comment: See rexcfnghk's answer. `List.Remove` will use reference equality if your `Building` object doesn't implement `GetHashCode` and `Equals`, so your `new Building` will never exist in the `buildingSelect` collection, and by definition can't be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can either override the equality in the class itself, IF this makes sense.

Or just make the check normally with `Any()`, like this:

```
    var q = (from building in BuildingList
        where buildingSelect.Any(b => b.Name == building.Name 
                                      && b.Status == building.Status)
        select building).ToList();
```