# C# List<myClass> Contains

Tags: c#, .net, class

Ok, so I have a List of type my own class, which in turn has parameters such as strings and integers, and I want to check inside my list with Contains() if I have a match with something a user would input.

As for the example you can assume there are already members in the list.

```
class Person 
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public Person()
    {
    }
}

class PersonList : Person
{
    List<Person> personList = new List<Person>();

    public bool Exist(int inputParameter)
    {
       if (personList.Contains(new Person { Id = inputParameter }))
       {
           return true;
       }
       else
       {
           return false;
       }
    }
}
```

Now even when I'm sure the input belongs to an already existing member of the list, my Exist method always returns false. Has anybody have any clue as to what I might not be doing right?

Comment: `personList.Any(person => person.Id == inputParameter);`

Comment: this does strict reference equals - think like c's pointers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ: "contains" and a Lambda query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566439/linq-contains-and-a-lambda-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `Any` instead `Contains`, try to change the code of `Exist` method to:

```
public bool Exist(int inputParameter)
{
    return personList.Any(person => person.Id == inputParameter);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `.Contains()` method [uses the default equality comparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=netframework-4.8#remarks), which means it calls the `.Equals()` method for the type to find a match.

For reference types like your `Person` class, the default method inherited from `Object` uses **reference equality**, meaning it will only return `true` if they are the *exact same object instance*. If you want a different type of comparison, you should overload the `Equals()` method in the type (and implement `IEquatable<T>` and override `GetHashCode()` while you're at it).

```
public class Person : IEquatable<Person>
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public bool Equals(Person other)
    {
        return other is Object && this.Id == other.Id;
    }

    public override bool Equals(Object other)
    {
        if (other is Person) return Equals((Person)other);
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {   //naive implementation. This is adequate as long as you're **SURE** all instances will have a unique/correct `Id` value.
        return this.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Going beyond this, **I would not build a separate `PersonList` type**. The `List<Person>` generic collection almost certainly already does the things you need.

That out of the way, it's still worthwhile to address how you might implement the `Exist()` method from the original `PersonList` class. One thing I would do here is avoid trying to allocate new objects to complete the search. With that in mind:

```
public bool Exist(int inputParameter)
{
    return personList.Any(p => p.Id == inputParameter);
}
```

Note, this will still currently allocate a new iterator object in most cases, but work is being done to make these linq operations more memory-friendly over time. It's also a whole lot less code. If you have a function that gives you a `boolean` result, there's no good reason to put it in an `if()` block just to return that same result.

And if we want to get really aggressive on the allocations, we can do it like this:

```
public bool Exist(int inputParameter)
{
    foreach(var p in personList)
    {
       if (p.Id == inputParameter) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8)

```
 public bool Exist(inputParameter)
    {
       if (personList.Any(person => person.Id == inputParameter))
       {
           return true;
       }
       else
       {
           return false;
       }
    }
```

Which you can collapse to just:

```
public bool Exist(inputParameter)
{
  return personList.Any(person => person.Id == inputParameter);
}
```

Comment: @Antnrmnd - I've changed it to use `Any` instead.

Comment: `Any` returns a boolean. Why make it so verbose?