# Joining 2 tables data in Linq with Contains

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a property '**CountryId**' in res1`list and I want to use it in join condition if c.CountryId exists in res1 but intellisense doesnt have Contains() method on`c.CountryId`, all I have in`c.ToString() `,`c.CompareTo()` and other inbuilt functions. How do I check if c.CountryId is among res1's CountryId?

```
 List<ClassA> res1 = new List<ClassA>();
  
  var result = await (from enumeration in db.Enumerations e
        join cust c in e.Id equals c.Id
        where c.CountryId .... 
        select c);
```

Comment: what is type of `c.Name`?

Comment: @LeiYang:Edited the question , it is an integer type I am interested in (CountryId)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ: "contains" and a Lambda query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566439/linq-contains-and-a-lambda-query)